# Detect Spelling Error at Compiletime instead of at Runtime in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

Assume you want to call a function `doPinch` each time a UIPinchGestureRecognizer recognizes a pinch gesture. This can be done in the following way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doPinch:")
}

func doPinch(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
  // do something
}
```

The former works fine but what if I refactor the name of `doPinch` or if I misspell the action name in the UIPinchGestureRecognizer constructor. In this way compilation work fine but I will get a runtime error. This is bad because it must be possible to check at compile time if the method name was spelled correctly.

Second example:

If you reference an image from the asset catalog I have to reference it like this:

```
 let image = UIImage(named: "yosemite-meadows")
```

Again, the same problem it compiles fine but I get a runtime error if the name of the image has a spelling error.

**How can I detect a spelling error at compile time instead of at runtime?**

Answer (score 0):

Patrick Hughes writing for Cocoa Is My Girlfriend has a solution for the image, string names problem. This is an Xcode integration solution but the final script may need tweaking to generate Swift specific files.

http://www.cimgf.com/2013/01/29/down-with-magic-strings/#more-2009